# Checking and proving unicity of solution of a system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the following system of equations:
$$\prod_{j=1}^K\alpha_j^{R_j} p_i+\prod_{j=1}^K(1-\alpha_j)^{R_j}(1-p_i)=y_{i,(R_1,\cdots,R_K)}$$
for each $i\in\{1,\cdots,I\}$ and each $(R_1,R_2,\cdots,R_K)\in\{0,1,\cdots,T\}^K$ satisfying $\sum\limits_{k=1}^K R_k=T$.

Here:

- $I\geq 2$, $K\geq 2$, $T\geq 2$  are integers
- the unknowns are $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^K$, $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^I$
- $0<\alpha_j<1$ for each $j=1,\cdots,K$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^K \alpha_j=1$
- $0<p_i<1$ for each $i=1,\cdots,I$
- the number of equations is $I×\binom{K+T-1}{K-1}$
- the quantities on the right-hand-side are known, potentially different across equations (this is why they have that complicated subscript)

**Question:** does the system has a unique solution? If yes, can we show it?

---

**Further discussion:**

The system above is a generalised version of a system that I have studied in a simplified setting where unicity holds. For example, for $I=2$, $K=2$, $T=2$, the system is:

$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha^2_1 p_1+(1-\alpha_1)^2(1-p_1)]=y_{1,(2,0)}\\
\alpha^2_2 p_1+(1-\alpha_2)^2(1-p_1)]=y_{1,(0,2)}\\
\alpha_1 \alpha_2 p_1+(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(1-p_1)]=y_{1,(1,1)}\\
{}^{\underline{\hphantom{\Huge------------}}}\\
\alpha^2_1 p_2+(1-\alpha_1)^2(1-p_2)]=y_{2,(2,0)}\\
\alpha^2_2 p_2+(1-\alpha_2)^2(1-p_2)] =y_{2,(0,2)}\\
\alpha_1 \alpha_2 p_2+(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(1-p_2)]=y_{2,(1,1)}
\end{cases}
$$
which can be shown to have a unique solution with respect to $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, p_1, p_2$ if $\alpha_1>1/2$. Just recalling that $\alpha_1=1-\alpha_2$, derivations are easy. I am unable to generalise such derivations though. Can you see some patterns/properties?

Comment: I think that the system has no solution since $1=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^K \alpha_j\gt \frac K2$ implies $K\lt 2$.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get this condition from? Can you write it based on my example with K=T=2?

Comment: It follows from "$1/2<\alpha_j<1$ for each $j=1,\dots,K$ and $\sum_{j=1}^K \alpha_j=1$" that $1=\sum_{j=1}^{K}\alpha_j\gt\frac{K}{2}$.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I've removed that.

Comment: Thanks @Saad. If I look at my simple example, I think that there should be a necessary (or, perhaps sufficient)  condition  on $T,K,I,\{\alpha_j\}$ such that the system has a unique solution. In my example, $K=T=I=2$ and $\alpha_1>\frac{1}{2}$ ensure a unique solution. Can we generalise that?

Comment: If I understand your comment, you are saying that if one of the $\alpha_j$ is known, then we have a unique solution. Could you write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

If $K=2$ and $T$ is even and there are two integers $i_1, i_2$ such that
$$y_{i_1,(T/2, T/2)}\not=y_{i_2,(T/2, T/2)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 1\le i_1\lt i_2\le I$$
then the system has no solution.

*Proof* :

For $(R_1,R_2)=(T/2,T/2)$, we have $I$ equations
$$\alpha_1^{T/2}\alpha_2^{T/2}p_i+(1-\alpha_1)^{T/2}(1-\alpha_2)^{T/2}(1-p_i)=y_{i,(T/2, T/2)}$$
which can be written as
$$\alpha_1^{T/2}\alpha_2^{T/2}=y_{i,(T/2, T/2)}$$
for every $i=1,2,\cdots, I$ since $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1$.

So, if there are two integers $i_1, i_2$ such that
$$y_{i_1,(T/2, T/2)}\not=y_{i_2,(T/2, T/2)}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 1\le i_1\lt i_2\le I$$
then the system has no solution.

---

**Added 1** : I'm going to add a generalization of "If $K=T=I=2$ and $\alpha_1\gt\frac 12$, then the system has at most one solution".

**Claim 1** : If $K=2$ and $T$ is even and $\alpha_1\gt \frac 12$, then the system has at most one solution.

*Proof* :

For $(R_1,R_2)=(T,0)$, we have
$$p_i\alpha_1^{T}+(1-p_i)(1-\alpha_1)^{T}=y_{i,(T,0)}$$
which can be written as
$$p_i(\alpha_1^{T}-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})=y_{i,(T,0)}-(1-\alpha_1)^{T}$$
for $i=1,2,\cdots, I$.

Here, note that
$$\alpha_1^{T}-(1-\alpha_1)^{T}=0\iff \alpha_1^{T}=(1-\alpha_1)^{T}\iff \alpha_1=\frac 12$$
from which we can say that if $\alpha_1\not=\frac 12$, then $p_i\ (i=1,2,\cdots, I)$ can be solved uniquely.

For $(R_1,R_2)=(T/2,T/2)$ with $i=1$, we have
$$\begin{align}&p_1\alpha_1^{T/2}\alpha_2^{T/2}+(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T/2}(1-\alpha_2)^{T/2}=y_{1,(T/2,T/2)}
\\\\&\iff p_1\alpha_1^{T/2}\alpha_2^{T/2}+(1-p_1)\alpha_1^{T/2}\alpha_2^{T/2}=y_{1,(T/2,T/2)}
\\\\&\iff \alpha_1^{T/2}\alpha_2^{T/2}=y_{1,(T/2,T/2)}
\\\\&\iff \alpha_1\alpha_2=y_{1,(T/2,T/2)}^{2/T}
\\\\&\iff\alpha_1^2-\alpha_1+y_{1,(T/2,T/2)}^{2/T}=0
\\\\&\iff\alpha_1=\frac 12\pm\frac{\sqrt{1-4y_{1,(T/2,T/2)}^{2/T}}}{2}\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can see that if $\alpha_1\gt \frac 12$, then the system has at most one solution.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

**Added 2** : I'm going to add another generalization for any $K\ge 2$.

**Claim 2** : If
$$\begin{cases}\alpha_1\not=\dfrac 12
\\\\b\ge 2^{-T}
\\\\\max\bigg(p,\dfrac{-b K T +bK + 2 b T - b + C T}{T(C+b)}\bigg)\lt\alpha_1\lt \min\bigg(q,\dfrac{b(T-1)}{T(C+b)}\bigg)\end{cases}$$where $p,q\ (p\lt q)$ are the roots of
$$K(1-2  T) \alpha_1^2 + (K T   + 2 T  - 2) \alpha_1+1- T=0$$with
$$b=y_{1,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)},\qquad C=\displaystyle\sum_{j=2}^{K}y_{1,(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,R_j=1,0,0,\cdots, 0)}$$
then the system has at most one solution.

*Proof* :

For $(R_1,R_2,\cdots, R_K)=(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)$, we have
$$p_i\alpha_1^{T} +(1-p_i)(1-\alpha_1)^{T}=y_{i,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)}$$
which can be written as
$$p_i(\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})=y_{i,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)}-(1-\alpha_1)^{T}\tag1$$
Here, note that
$$\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T}=0\iff \alpha_1^T=(1-\alpha_1)^{T}\iff \alpha_1=\frac 12$$
So, if $\alpha_1\not=\frac 12$, then $p_i\ (i=1,2,\cdots, I)$ can be solved uniquely.

For $i=1$ and $(R_1,R_2,\cdots, R_K)=(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,1,0,0,\cdots, 0)$ where $R_j=1$ with $j\not=1$, we have

$$p_1\alpha_1^{T-1}\alpha_j+(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}(1-\alpha_j)=y_{1,(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,1,0,0,\cdots, 0)}$$
which can be written as
$$\alpha_j(p_1\alpha_1^{T-1}-(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1})=y_{1,(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,1,0,0,\cdots, 0)}-(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}$$

Here, note that
$$\begin{align}&p_1\alpha_1^{T-1}-(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}=0
\\\\&\implies p_1(\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1})=(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}
\\\\&\implies p_1(\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})(\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1})=(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}(\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})
\\\\&\implies (b-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})(\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1})=(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}(\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})
\\\\&\implies b(\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1})= 
 \alpha_1^{T-1}(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}
\\\\&\implies \frac{\alpha_1^{T-1}(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}{\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}=b\end{align}$$
where $b:=y_{1,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)}$.

So, if
$$\frac{\alpha_1^{T-1}(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}{\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}\not=b$$
then $\alpha_j\ (j=2,3,\cdots, K)$ can be solved uniquely.

Using $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{K}\alpha_j=1$, we have

$$\alpha_1+\sum_{j=2}^{K}\frac{y_{1,(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,R_j=1,0,0,\cdots, 0)}-(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}{p_1\alpha_1^{T-1}-(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}=1$$
which can be written as

$$(1-\alpha_1)(p_1\alpha_1^{T-1}-(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1})=C-(K-1)(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1},$$
i.e.
$$p_1(1-\alpha_1)\alpha_1^{T-1}-C=(1-p_1)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}(2-\alpha_1-K)$$
where $C:=\displaystyle\sum_{j=2}^{K}y_{1,(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,R_j=1,0,0,\cdots, 0)}$.

Multiplying the both sides by $(\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})$ and using $(1)$ for $i=1$ give

$$(b-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})(1-\alpha_1)\alpha_1^{T-1}-C(\alpha_1^T-(1-\alpha_1)^{T})+(\alpha_1^T-b)(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}(\alpha_1+K-2)=0\tag2$$

Let $f(\alpha_1)$ be the LHS of $(2)$.

Then, we have

$$f'(\alpha_1) =\alpha_1^{T-2}(1-\alpha_1)^{T-2}\bigg( K(1-2  T) \alpha_1^2 + (k T   + 2 T  - 2) \alpha_1+1- T\bigg)+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-2}\bigg(  T(C  + b  )\alpha_1+b K T -bK  - 2 b T + b  - C T\bigg)+\alpha_1^{T-2}\bigg(-T(C+b)\alpha_1 + Tb - b \bigg) ​$$

Therefore, if

$$K(1-2  T) \alpha_1^2 + (K T   + 2 T  - 2) \alpha_1+1- T\gt 0\tag3$$
$$T(C  + b  )\alpha_1+b K T -bK  - 2 b T + b  - C T \gt 0\tag4$$
and
$$-T(C+b)\alpha_1 + Tb - b\gt 0\tag5$$

then we get $f'(\alpha_1)\gt 0$, so $(2)$ has at most one solution.

Since $$(4)(5)\iff \frac{-b K T +bK + 2 b T - b + C T}{T(C+b)}\lt\alpha_1\lt \frac{b(T-1)}{T(C+b)}$$
letting $p,q(p\lt q)$ be the roots of $$K(1-2  T) \alpha_1^2 + (K T   + 2 T  - 2) \alpha_1+1- T=0$$ we have
$$(3)(4)(5)\iff \max\bigg(p,\frac{-b K T +bK + 2 b T - b + C T}{T(C+b)}\bigg)\lt\alpha_1\lt \min\bigg(q,\frac{b(T-1)}{T(C+b)}\bigg)$$

Also, let $g(\alpha_1)=\dfrac{\alpha_1^{T-1}(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}{\alpha_1^{T-1}+(1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}}$. Then, we have
$$\dfrac{\partial g(\alpha_1)}{\partial \alpha_1}=\frac{(T-1)\alpha_1^{T-2}(1-\alpha_1)^{T-2}((1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}-\alpha_1^{T-1})}{((1-\alpha_1)^{T-1}+\alpha_1^{T-1})^2}$$
so $g(\alpha_1)$ is increasing for $\alpha_1\lt 1/2$ and decreasing for $\alpha_1\gt 1/2$. Therefore, we can say that if $g(1/2)=2^{-T}\le b$, then $g(\alpha_1)\not=b$. This means that we can say that if $b\ge 2^{-T}$, then $\alpha_j\ (j=2,3,\cdots, K)$ can be solved uniquely.

In conclusion, if
$$\begin{cases}\alpha_1\not=\dfrac 12
\\\\b\ge 2^{-T}
\\\\\max\bigg(p,\dfrac{-b K T +bK + 2 b T - b + C T}{T(C+b)}\bigg)\lt\alpha_1\lt \min\bigg(q,\dfrac{b(T-1)}{T(C+b)}\bigg)\end{cases}$$where $p,q\ (p\lt q)$ are the roots of
$$K(1-2  T) \alpha_1^2 + (K T   + 2 T  - 2) \alpha_1+1- T=0$$with
$$b=y_{1,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)},\qquad C=\displaystyle\sum_{j=2}^{K}y_{1,(T-1,0,0,\cdots, 0,R_j=1,0,0,\cdots, 0)}$$
then the system has at most one solution.$\quad\blacksquare$.

Comment: I'm trying to work out on your proof of claim 2. I was checking the sufficient conditions for $T=K=2$, $b=\frac{0.2}{0.3}$ and $c=\frac{0.15}{0.3}$. I obtain the roots $p=\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6}$ and $q=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6}$. By applying your condition 3, I get $\max\{\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6}, 0.97\}<\alpha_1<\min \{\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6}, 0.39\}$. This is never verified because $\min \{\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6}, 0.39\}<\max\{\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6}, 0.97\}$. Should I take this as indication of the fact that the system has no solution for these specific numbers?

Comment: Also, when you show that $\alpha_2,...,\alpha_K$ can be solved uniquely once we know $p_1$ and $\alpha_1$: should the arrows be "$\iff$" rather than "$\Rightarrow$"?

Comment: I was also wondering about the following: in the part where you write "$f'(\alpha_1)>0$, so (2) has AT MOST one solution". Here, should I interpret this as "(2) has no solutions or 1 solution"?

Comment: Related to the above, do you have used somewhere that $\alpha_h\neq 0,1$ for each $h=1,...,H$ and that $p_i\neq 0,1$ for each $i=1,...,I$? It does not seem so, but perhaps it is hidden somewhere.

Comment: @TEX : (1) No, in that case, we know nothing about solutions of the system. (2) Yes, you can replace $\implies$ with $\iff$ there. (3) Yes, that means that "(2) has no solutions or 1 solution". (4) Yes, I used $\alpha_1\not=0,1$ to see that $g(\alpha_1)$ is not a constant function.

Comment: Thanks. $g$ has a bell shape: it is increasing for $\alpha_1\in [0,\frac{1}{2})$; decreasing for $\alpha_1\in [\frac{1}{2},1]$; with maximum at $\alpha_1=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, if $B\geq 2^{-t}$, then $g(\alpha_1)\neq B$ for each $\alpha_1\in [0,1]$ (including $\alpha_1\in \{0,1\}$). I don't see the problem of having $\alpha_1\in \{0,1\}$ when we study $g$. Instead, I can see a problem of having $\alpha_1\in \{0,1\}$ when we study $f$: if $\alpha_1\in \{0,1\}$, then (3) is violated. Is this correct? Also, $p_1,..., p_I, \alpha_2,..., \alpha_H$ can be equal to $0,1$?

Comment: @TEX : Ah, that is correct. If $y_{i,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)}=(1-\alpha_1)^{T}$, then $p_i=0$. If $y_{i,(T,0,0,\cdots, 0)}=\alpha_1^T$, then $p_i=1$. So, $p_i$ can be equal to $0,1$. Similarly, $\alpha_j\ (j\ge 2)$ can be equal to $0,1$.

Comment: Thanks. I also think that it should be $B>2^{-t}$ (strict inequality).

Comment: @TEX : We already have $\alpha_1\not=\frac 12$, so $B\ge 2^{-T}$ works.

Comment: I was also wondering: could we also consider the case where (3), (4), (5) are strictly negative? I think that also in that case $f(\alpha_1)$ would have one root at most.

Comment: @TEX : You are right. Yes, we could.

Answer (score 3):

$\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}\def\Rsum{\sum_{\substack{R_1, \cdots, R_K \geqslant 0\\R_1 + \cdots + R_K = T}} }$Firstly, $p_i$'s can be solved uniquely: Since\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom=} \Rsum \frac{T!}{R_1! \cdots R_K!} y_{i, (R_1, \cdots, R_K)}\\
&= \Rsum \frac{T!}{R_1! \cdots R_K!} \paren{ p_i \prod_{j = 1}^K α_j^{R_j} + (1 - p_i) \prod_{j = 1}^K (1 - α_j)^{R_j} }\\
&= p_i \Rsum \frac{T!}{R_1! \cdots R_K!} \prod_{j = 1}^K α_j^{R_j}  + (1 - p_i) \Rsum \frac{T!}{R_1! \cdots R_K!} \prod_{j = 1}^K (1 - α_j)^{R_j}\\
&= p_i \paren{ \sum_{j = 1}^K α_j }^T + (1 - p_i) \paren{ \sum_{j = 1}^K (1 - α_j) }^T\\
&= p_i + (K - 1)^T (1 - p_i),
\end{align*}
then$$
p_i = \frac{1}{(K - 1)^T - 1} \Biggl( (K - 1)^T - \Rsum \frac{T!}{R_1! \cdots R_K!} y_{i, (R_1, \cdots, R_K)} \Biggr).
$$

Now consider a fixed $i_0$. For each $j$, there is\begin{gather*}
α_j^T p_{i_0} + (1 - α_j)^T (1 - p_{i_0}) = y_{i_0, (0, \cdots, 0, T, 0, \cdots 0)}. \tag{1}
\end{gather*}
Since$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial α_j}(α_j^T p_{i_0} + (1 - α_j)^T (1 - p_{i_0})) = T (α_j^{T - 1} p_{i_0} - (1 - α_j)^{T - 1} (1 - p_{i_0})),
$$
then $α_j^T p_{i_0} + (1 - α_j)^T (1 - p_{i_0})$ is strictly decreasing with respect to $α_j$ for $α_j \in (0, α^*)$ and strictly increasing for $α_j \in (α^*, 1)$, where $α^* = \dfrac{(1 - p_{i_0})^{\frac{1}{T - 1}}}{p_{i_0}^{\frac{1}{T - 1}} + (1 - p_{i_0})^{\frac{1}{T - 1}}}$. Thus (1) implies that there are at most two values of $α_j$.

Furthur more, if one of $α_j$'s is known, say $α_1$, then for each $j ≠ 1$, there is$$
α_1^{T - 1} α_j p_{i_0} + (1 - α_1)^{T - 1} (1 - α_j) (1 - p_{i_0}) = y_{i_0, (T - 1, 0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots 0)},
$$
which implies that\begin{gather*}
(p_{i_0} α_1^{T - 1} - (1 - p_{i_0}) (1 - α_1)^{T - 1}) α_j = y_{i_0, (T - 1, 0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots 0)} - (1 - p_{i_0}) (1 - α_1)^{T - 1}. \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
If $p_{i_0} α_1^{T - 1} - (1 - p_{i_0}) (1 - α_1)^{T - 1} ≠ 0$, i.e. $α_1 ≠ α^*$, then (2) shows that$$
α_j = \frac{y_{i_0, (T - 1, 0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots 0)} - (1 - p_{i_0}) (1 - α_1)^{T - 1}}{p_{i_0} α_1^{T - 1} - (1 - p_{i_0}) (1 - α_1)^{T - 1}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Are you using that the alpha's sum up to 1?

Comment: @TEX If you mean the derivation of $p_i$, yes.